# Why does Bane want to destroy Gotham city?

Tags: analysis, the-dark-knight-rises

In [The Dark Knight Rises](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/), at the end of the movie Talia said, it was her father's dream to destroy Gotham city, and I accept that any daughter who was in that situation will definitely  think to destroy Gotham to fulfill her father's dream.

But, I don't understand ***why does Bane want to fulfill the dream of Ra's al Ghul***?

He was expelled from the **League of Shadows** by **Ra's al Ghul**. So, any man who was in that position would definitely have furious anger over Ra's al Ghul and take vengeance. But Bane didn't do that, despite his ex-communication from the League of Shadows why would he want to work for **Ra's al Ghul**'s dream?  Unless it is because he's in love with Talia?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Bane said, he viewed himself as carrying on the League of Shadows' mission in the wake of Ra's' death.  As Ra's explained in *Batman Begins*, the League periodically culls civilizations, and Gotham was next.  Batman prevented their attempt in *Batman Begins*, but Bane returned to finish the job in *The Dark Knight Rises*.

Given the revelation at the end of Talia's identity and role, much of the above still holds.  However, instead of Bane being the leader, he was simply a top lieutenant following Talia's orders.  Talia's motivation was more of a revenge thing.  She wanted to get back at Batman/Bruce for killing her father.  And the thing that Bruce cares about most is Gotham, so slowly and painfully destroying that would give her the vengeance she desired over the loss of her father.

Answer (score 7):

"Doesn't matter who we are, what matters is our plan".

We find that the plan is to destroy Gotham, it doesn't matter who is carrying this out, whoever they are, they are upholding and executing a plan. Well, in order to see the plan in its purest form, we have to ask "Whose plan was it originally, it doesn't matter who is pursuing it now, but what was the original plan?"

To answer this, we have to go all the way back to Batman Begins, it is Ra's Al Gul's plan. So the question isn't really "Why does Bane want to destroy Gotham?" but "Why does Ra's Al Gul want to destroy Gotham?" He explains in the League of Shadows' Temple while training Bruce (albeit, Ducard rather than Ra's). He says that Gotham is the epitome of corruption and injustice and has to be taken out to restore balance and justice.

Now, sure, Bane and Thalia have their own reasons for wanting to uphold this plan. Talia wants to simultaneously punish her father's murderer and accomplish his incomplete work. Bane wants to support Thalia as he sees her as purity and redemption, he maybe even has romantic feelings toward her (which is more literarily ambiguous than commonly thought).

BUT THE WHY IS TRACED ALL THE WAY BEYOND BANE AND TALIA!

Think of that theory and reconsider the line "it doesn't matter who we are, what matters is our plan"

Answer (score 2):

Bane's view of the world is twisted due to living in the Pit. When he protected Talia in the Pit, he was rewarded by being trained in the League Of Shadows. He considers the League his family, as demonstrated in the opening Plane scene where one of his henchmen is willing to die. After Ras died, Talia forgave him as he did more good for her than bad. She inherited the League and undid the excommunication. Bane wants to prove himself as their leader. Not just out of love, but out of moral and personal duty. He also believes Gotham City is corrupt due to finding Gordon's letter and working with John Daggett.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found, or giving us the rationale behind your ideas and conclusions. I hope you enjoy participating.